Google Search page always light theme
Is there any way to force the light theme on the Google Search page (google.com)?, let's say that the page always loads the light theme regardless of the history or browser cookies. I'm using Brave Browser.

Yes, you can force the light theme on Google Search regardless of your browser's history or cookies using the following methods:
Use Browser Extensions:
Dark Reader Extension: Although primarily used to enable dark mode, you can configure it to enforce light mode. Install the Dark Reader extension, go to the extension settings, and turn off dark mode for Google Search. This effectively forces the light theme.

Yes, you can force the Google Search page to always load in light theme regardless of your browser's history, cookies, or system settings. Since you are using the Brave browser, here’s how you can do it:
Method 1: Use a URL Parameter
Google allows users to force a light or dark theme using a URL parameter. You can bookmark the following URL to always open Google Search in light mode:
https://www.google.com/?hl=en&gl=us&theme=light
This URL forces the light theme every time you load the page.
Method 2: Use a Browser Extension
If you prefer a more automated solution, you can use a browser extension that enforces a light theme on specific websites. You can use Stylus Extension or Dark Reader Extension.
Method 3: Disable Browser's Dark Mode Feature
